# run BLDC motor WD-1465FD of LG washing machine with frequency inverter Sunfar E300-2S0022L

Tags: motor, brushless-dc-motor

I have a BLDC motor WD-1465FD of washing machine LG . My question is can I drive the  bldc motor (directly) with inverter Sunfar E300-2S0022L.

I tried all VFD parameters but no good results. 
 It only starts on 200v but after 30 sec. starts burning.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. (1) Please edit your question to capitalise and punctuate both the title and question properly if you want to be taken seriously. (2) Don't assume that we're all familiar with the parts you have mentioned. Add links to the datasheets for each. (3) "*I tried to put in all the parameters ...*". Nobody can help you with this if you don't list your parameters. Is this not obvious?

Comment: I mean, if you're going to make a question, shouldn't you at least spend some effort to make sure there's no obvious grammatical errors? Also, I don't see any question mark anywhere (looks like this "?"). Call me pedantic.

Comment: inverter must handle surge power , 5~8x ? rated power. that's why. also manual says... **Capacitor: The capacitors in inverter may explode when they are burned.
Plastic: Poisonous gas may be generated when front panel is burned, please pay attention to
waste gas when plastic parts are burned.**

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 what's the point in editing a question if you're not going to fix all the grammar?

Comment: Good point.  Corrected.   I wonder if he started with 0.1Hz and ramped up in a few seconds to 5Hz with V/F constant slope.    
         5Hz slow RPM is 3.6% of 140Hz fast spin yet starting current must be >10x to accelerate, but with low carrier f, inductance increases current, not sure how that works. I guess it doesn't

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot.

The Sunfar E300-2S0022L seems to be a typical variable frequency drive for **3-phase induction motors** as found in machine tools.  It varies the frequency and likely voltage of the drive to accomplish speed control, but it relies on the ability of the *induced* magnets in an induction motor's rotor to "slip" or migrate through the iron, in order to achieve (near) synchronization of the loaded rotor with the drive frequency.

In contrast, the motor from a WD-1465FD actually is a 3-phase permanent magnet motor as you claim.  The use of these in appliances is a newer idea, but with drive electronics becomes possible.

Notably, PMDC motors cannot "slip" because rather than being induced poles which can migrate, their permanent magnets are attached at specific points on the rotor.  Instead, the driver must *detect* the position of the magnets on the rotor to calculate the proper waveform phase.  At high speeds, this can be done by detecting back EMF from the coils as the magnet poles pass, and a driver for something like an airplane propeller that prevents very little torque load at low speed can even get a motor started with an open loop algorithm to the point of moving enough for the back EMF detection to "find" the rotor.

But a motor that runs at low speed, and that needs to startup with torque to move a big drum full of wet clothes needs a more reliable way to measure rotor position at low speeds.  Your motor does this with what look to be an array of 3 sensors which detect the permanent magnets in the rotor - so in addition to the 3-lead power connection to the driver, it has another multi-lead connection for the sensors.

[image: Motor Stator image from parts supplier http://www.europart.nl/a/lg-motor-4417ea1002g-wd1485-wd1465fd-06346020]
(WD-1465FD motor's stator, image from parts supplier http://www.europart.nl/a/lg-motor-4417ea1002g-wd1485-wd1465fd-06346020)

**You cannot drive this PMDC motor with a driver meant for Induction Motors** - the control algorithm is wrong, and there's no input for the sensors to inform a control algorithms estimate of rotor position.  You may have gotten it to run a little - unloaded and spun up somehow it might loaf along open loop.  But it won't have useful torque and can easily lose synchronization and merely vibrate, and/or enter faults where it pulls excessive current as no meaningful back EMF is being generated to oppose the voltages applied in expectation of a overcoming the high back EMF of the expected high rotation rate.

You *might* be able to drive the motor "crudely" with a "sensored" BLDC driver meant for electric bicycle hub motors or something like that, but really the best driver is the one in the washing machine, as that has been engineered and tuned to the specific motor.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**    Short Answer: maybe
  [Hopefully you know more about motors, than this guy who was eventually successful.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xpb9JUaWl7M)

After reviewing some Youtube Videos on the Sunfar E300-2S0022L with Mach3 CNC software, It has the acceleration software variables that allow you to optimize the torque to your expected load to accelerate to full speed.  Being a 3 phase VFD , you can power it with 220Vac(and others) split **single-phase** or 3 Phase input and it converts to DC then 3 Phase AC for the motor while increasing V with RPM of the motor according to the constants applied in Mach 3 software for number of poles, Max V, max RPM and Acceleration Time (seconds).  Then you can control the RPM directly with screen software settings and much more.

[image]
 Note the limitations of open loop  vs closed Loop with encoder or Hall sensors for V/F control to prevent saturation of core yet maximize torque.
(not necessarily to scale)

### Looks like a very good budget solution.

end edit

---

### Info:

Smart VFD Inverter rated 2.2kW 220V 3ph motor delta induction motor using carrier 1.5~12kHz and commutation rate of 0.1Hz to 1kHz with 20% boost option and variable ramp and V/F ratios.

LG draws 2.1kW 1ph 220V, with integrated driver.

Choosing proper driver requires scoping motor power and Hall pole sensor signals.

I was assuming he was powering the entire unit. But if not, and  attempting to convert  a BLDC to a VFD drive motor, you may need to include commutation feedback.

[image]

Note 5 pin power and 3 pin index sensor.

The motor runs from 0 to 50 RPM then in spin mode 600 RPM to 1400 RPM

There are 36 poles or 18 pole pairs or 6pairs per phase thus 50 RPM = 50RPM/60s*6p= **5Hz** and 1400RPM= 1400rpm/60s*6p= **140Hz**.

Did you try V/F settings for 0~2V/Hz assuming 280Vac@140Hz is what you can measure to verify?

I  now expect  5 pin sensor for 3 phase Hall sense and DC using 1 pole sense for all 6 poles.

Did you assume  motor was BLDC but is actually Induction Motor and not Variable Reluctance Motor.  Sensorless control requires more work with Vector current sense.

Expand your question to cover all unknowns.

I have never used either of these parts, but I would scope the LG power and sensor signals and add to question before trying to drive externally then you can compare with Sunfar E300 output.

Comment: This is incorrect.  The *appliance* may be single phase, but the motor is not a single phase induction motor.  **It actually is a 3 phase brushless DC motor** as the poster claims.  You can see a picture of the stator with 3 power wires and what is very clearly a rotor position sensor here: http://www.europart.nl/a/lg-motor-4417ea1002g-wd1485-wd1465fd-06346020

Comment: I was assuming he was powering the unit and since no block diagram was given, how do we know if direct drive he wired it correctly with Hall sensor feedback and winding orientation.

Comment: A VFD intended for an induction motor doesn't support that.

Comment: we dont even know if motor is unique or Y symmetric current

Comment: Well, *you* are still mixing up the power and sensor connectors...  Have you ever looked inside a sensored PMDC motor?

Comment: Never seen it before. So 5 pin sensor does what?  hall sense for 1 pole? then 3 phase Delta is OK with Hall feedback.

Comment: The 5-wire sensor schemes seem to have 3 phases of sensing and power and ground. See for example http://i01.i.aliimg.com/img/pb/270/828/497/497828270_921.jpg

Comment: hi..thanx for your comment and i saw that in https://youtu.be/yaIUp9ZzjYU

Comment: by the way the hall sensor of that BLDC motor is 4wire 12+ ground and 2 comunication wires

Comment: Yes 2 phase uses 2 signals and 3 phase uses 3

Comment: that BLDC  LGWD-1465FD  is 3 phase the one phase is floating...i make some researching tru internet and found out that the new washing machine  that  using AC inverter is simillar to that bldc motor

Comment: by the way i tried to use e-bike controller but it has another problem  it is from 60 to 120 degree and the bldc motor have 30 degree angle..and this motor is  Y wiring

Comment: it looks like 2 phase motor with 18 poles on 3 pin power and 5 pin signal or 20 deg per step

Comment: i told you it has 4 pin not 5 pin hall sensor...on the pic you see 5 pins but i have 5 hall sensors from  5 BLDC  motor and have got apart that hall sensor it has 5 pins but one of them is not connected only 4pins working...one 12+ one ground  2 wires for comunication

Comment: 30 degree from the 1st phase to last one..12x30=360degree...the e-bike  controller have 5 pins hall sensor i have 2,4kw one

Comment: can i drive  BLDC LGWD-1465FD motor with that stepper motor driver controller   https://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/3M860-3-Phase-Stepper-Motor-Driver-Controller-for-CNC-Router-Laser-Engraving-Machine/1391641_32800974167.html

Comment: 80Vdc? 5.8Arms  maybe not alone.  Get a 3 phase VFD motor driver  and controller rated for this .

Comment: did you report coil DCR yet?

Comment: i am wondering if  i put in arduino mega 2560 to sunfar e 300 and run it over PC with some software

Comment: is the 3phase VFD motor driver is similar with B-EMF at Turngy ..sensorless control

Comment: What is the coil DC resistance ?

Comment: you mean for any coils of 3phase..they are connected on Y...have todisconect any wires to measure any of  them or

Comment: phase to common from connector

Comment: it is about 1540 omh

Comment: i am wondering if i can rewiring this BLDC motor on 120 degree 4poles per each phase 9x4poles it has 12pairs of magnets

Comment: if i rewire on 120 degree 9x4 bobins it has 12 pairs magnets then try to with sunfar e300-2s0022l

Comment: hi..again..i wanna ask if someone knows this motor WD-1465FD above...i think that the new DELTA inverter have almost the same chips..like back-emf at turnigy for drons....which DELTA inverter model have that chip

Comment: Are you trying to make a sensorless VFD for a drone?  ;)

Comment: https://www.google.ca/search?client=firefox-b&dcr=0&tbm=isch&q=B-EMF+at+Turnigy+3+phase&chips=q:b+emf+at+turnigy+3+phase,online_chips:circuit&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiR29TNq5TZAhXic98KHSi5CIQQ4lYIKigC&biw=1248&bih=606&dpr=1.54

Comment: nope...i try to run ...BLDC  WD-1465FD ..above...with some driver  and nothing ....i meant that some new DELTA inverter have the same chip like BACK-EMF at TURNIGY .i have found before in the google how s the name of that chip but i losted it...that chips can be found in the TURNIGY back-emf...i wonder if anyone knows that chip name  of DELTA inverter

Comment: maybe one of these http://vesselyn.com/ZXNjLXNjaGVtYXRpYw/

Comment: or https://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showthread.php?140454-five(5)-diy-brushless-ESC-designs

Comment: If you do not use the Hall sensors then your acceleration must be reduced to prevent skipping/stalling like a stepper motor. The Hall sensor gives rotor position feedback to make sure it has moved before commutating to the next phase. The other method is VFD/ back EMF. Is that what you wanted??

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xpb9JUaWl7M

Comment: thanx..for answer i thought that my Sunfar E300-2S0022L that  i have...have the same VFD/back EMF  but it seems do not have it...i meant doyou know the models of Delta or some others that have that VFD/back EMF...and by the way whats VFD meannings..i saw that youtube videos  ..but i want to run WD-1465FD motor..by the way i have a power supply and board complect from LG washing machine and it runs the motor as unipolar bldc stepper motor with ULN2004A driver chip and TOSHIBA TD62783AP 0034KS chip driver

Comment: i wonder if i can run that motor with some like this https://www.aliexpress.com/item/hall-sensor-feedback-24v-48v-bldc-motor-driver-15A/32838365458.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.157.71be3344DWusNE&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_2_10152_10151_10065_10344_10068_10342_10325_10546_10343_10340_10548_10341_10084_10083_10618_10304_10307_10313_10059_10534_100031_10103_10626_10625_10624_10623_10622_10621_10620_10142,searchweb201603_25,ppcSwitch_5&algo_expid=82dcdc27-2599-4dec-b1cf-023b6e0c2199-28&algo_pvid=82dcdc27-2599-4dec-b1cf-023b6e0c2199&priceBeautifyAB=0

Comment: or this............https://www.aliexpress.com/item/300watt-500watt-600watt-bldc-motor-driver-24volt-48volt-30amp/32839284413.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.84.71be3344DWusNE&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_2_10152_10151_10065_10344_10068_10342_10325_10546_10343_10340_10548_10341_10084_10083_10618_10304_10307_10313_10059_10534_100031_10103_10626_10625_10624_10623_10622_10621_10620_10142,searchweb201603_25,ppcSwitch_5&algo_expid=82dcdc27-2599-4dec-b1cf-023b6e0c2199-16&algo_pvid=82dcdc27-2599-4dec-b1cf-023b6e0c2199&priceBeautifyAB=0

Comment: It would work but at 48V vs 220V you only get 48/220 x rated RPM and 22% of  kW output.  since V/f is a constant limit

Comment: or this...https://www.aliexpress.com/item/3-phase-stepper-motor-driver-3DM860D-Voltage-24-80VDC-current-range-2-4-7-2A/32819379336.html?spm=a2g0s.13010208.9

Comment: thanx..by the way Sunfar E300-2S0022L seems do not have VFD/back EMF..right ...only the new models of inverter have right....i meant i have to take the correct models of inverter that have /VFD/back EMF...right